# Nested for loop slowing down for unknown reason (autoit)

Tags: loops, limit, autoit

My code:

```
Func myFunc()

    $lag = 1300
    while (1)
        MouseMove(870, 189)
        sleep(10)
        LC(870, 189)
        sleep(1200 + $lag)
        LC(1010,333)
        sleep(100)
        RC(826,115)
        sleep(50)
        LC(870,212)
        sleep(50)
        send("{ESC}")
        sleep(150)
        $x = 0
        $y = 0

        For $i = 0 To 27 Step 1
            sleep(11)
            MouseClick("left", 1158 + $x ,260 + $y)
            $x+=42
            if ($x = 168) Then
                $x = 0
                $y+=36
            EndIf
        Next

    WEnd

EndFunc
```

The only delay within the for loop is the sleep(11) but it takes about .5 seconds (500ms) for each iteration rather than 11ms + whatever small delay. Also, completely removing the sleep(11) part of the loop still results in an approximately 500ms delay.

Incase anyone was wondering, it's a video game macro; the first part of the while loop opens an interface and sets something up while the second part (the for loop) is suppose to click through the inventory very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The mouse cursor takes time to move. Set the speed parameter to 0 to make it move instantly

```
MouseClick("left", 1158 + $x ,260 + $y,1,0)
```